# Hilbert's Nullstellensatz and prime divisors of polynomials

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $P$ be a polynomial with integer coefficients. A prime $p$ is said to be a prime divisor of $P$ if $p$ divides $P(n)$ for some integer $n$. Define $S(P)$ to be the set of prime divisors of $P$.

Let $P_1, P_2, \dots, P_k$ be a set of polynomials in $\mathbb{Z}[x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n]=\mathbb{Z}[X]$

Hilbert's Nullstellensatz says if there are polynomials $R_1, R_2, \dots, R_k$ in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$ verifying
$$\begin{align}P_1R_1 + P_2R_2 +  \dots + P_kR_k = 1.  \tag{1}\label{eq1}\end{align}$$ if and only if the system $$P_1(X)=...=P_m(X) = 0$$ has no complex solutions

In Lou van den Dries, *A remark on Ax's theorem on solvability modulo primes*, Math. Z. 208, 65 70 (1991) (https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02571510) the author proved in **Proposition 2.7** that if equation (1) holds then $S(P_1, P_2, \dots, P_k)$ is finite. Here $S(P_1, P_2, \dots, P_k)$ is the set of common prime divisors of all polynomials $P_1, P_2, \dots, P_k$

Now, I have two **questions**:

(1) Can one explain in some details how the author *deduce* that $S(P_1, P_2, \dots, P_k)$ is finite.

(2) Is the result still holds if one consider the **strong Hilbert's Nullstellensatz**, i.e., there are polynomials $R_1, R_2, \dots, R_k$ in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$ verifying
$$\begin{align}P_1R_1 + P_2R_2 +  \dots + P_kR_k = R(X)^r.  \tag{2}\label{eq2}\end{align}$$ if and only if the system $$P_1(X)=...=P_m(X) = 0$$ has no complex solutions. Here $R(X)$ is a non zero polynomial and $r$ is a positive integer.

Comment: (1): multiply by the denominators of the $R_i$.

Comment: @Mindlack: Can you elaborate with this idea.

Comment: Assume that the RHS is instead a nonzero integer and the $R_i$ have integer coefficients. Can you deduce the result?

Comment: @Mindlack: Still not understand your point.

Comment: There is an integer $N$ such that every $Q_i=NR_i$ has integer coefficients. Then $\sum_i{P_iQ_i}=N$. So any prime in $S(P_1,\ldots,P_k)$ must divide $N$.